# Updated scope variable not showed by view. Promises not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I'm trying to retrieve data from my Firebase Database, and corresponding images from Firebase Storage. The problem is, my view does not want to update itself with the data.

If I try to simply fetch the data from my database, it works perfectly. Once I add functionality to fetch pictures (which takes slightly longer) it looks like my view simply looks immediately at the scope variable and does not wait for $scope.friendsinfo to update. I think I'm doing something wrong with my promises and should be using $q, but I have no idea how exactly. Can anyone tell me what the best way would be to go about this? Thanks a lot!

```
var friendsRef = firebase.database().ref('friendships/' + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);

$scope.friends = $firebaseArray(friendsRef);

$scope.friendsinfo = [];

$scope.$watch('friends', function() {
    var newfriends = $scope.friends;
    var newfriendsinfo = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < newfriends.length; i++){
        var ref = firebase.database().ref('users/' + newfriends[i].$id);
        var profilePicRef = firebase.storage().ref("profilepictures/" + newfriends[i].$id + "/profilepicture");
        var picPromise = fetchPicture(profilePicRef);

        var newfriendid = newfriends[i].$id;
        var newfriendagreed = newfriends[i].agreed;

        picPromise.then(function(data){
            ref.once('value', function(snapshot){
                newfriendsinfo.push({
                    id: newfriendid,
                    name: snapshot.val().name,
                    email: snapshot.val().email,
                    agreed: newfriendagreed,
                    profilepicture: data //This is the functionality that causes my view to not display the updated $scope.friendsinfo because it takes too long.
                });
            });
        });
    }
    $scope.friendsinfo = newfriendsinfo;
    alert($scope.friendsinfo.length);
}, true);

function fetchPicture(ref){
    return ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
        return url;
    }).catch(function(error) {
        alert("error");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not got your code properly but posting code which will you to guide that how to use promises with resolve approach :

```
  function asyncGreet(name) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();

  setTimeout(function() {
  deferred.notify('About to greet ' + name + '.');

  if (okToGreet(name)) {
  deferred.resolve('Hello, ' + name + '!');
  } else {
      deferred.reject('Greeting ' + name + ' is not allowed.');
  }
  }, 1000);

  return deferred.promise;
}

var promise = asyncGreet('Robin Hood');
promise.then(function(greeting) {
  alert('Success: ' + greeting);
}, function(reason) {
  alert('Failed: ' + reason);
}, function(update) {
  alert('Got notification: ' + update);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone ever needs the solution, here it is. Turns out the problem is mainly caused by waiting for the for loop to finish, for which each item in term waits for another function to finish. This is how I was able to solve it. It's probably not optimal, but it'll do for now :)

```
var friendsRef = firebase.database().ref('friendships/' + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);

$scope.friends = $firebaseArray(friendsRef);

$scope.friendsinfo = [];

$scope.$watch('friends', function() {
    var newfriends = $scope.friends;

    asyncUpdateFriendsInfo(newfriends).then(function(newlist){
        $scope.friendsinfo = newlist;
    });
}, true);

function fetchPicture(ref){
    return ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
        return url;
    }).catch(function(error) {
        alert("error");
    });
}

function asyncUpdateFriendsInfo(newfriends){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var newfriendsinfo = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < newfriends.length; i++){
        var ref = firebase.database().ref('users/' + newfriends[i].$id);
        var profilePicRef = firebase.storage().ref("profilepictures/" + newfriends[i].$id + "/profilepicture");
        var picPromise = fetchPicture(profilePicRef);

        var newfriendid = newfriends[i].$id;
        var newfriendagreed = newfriends[i].agreed;

        picPromise.then(function(data){
            ref.once('value', function(snapshot){
                newfriendsinfo.push({
                    id: newfriendid,
                    name: snapshot.val().name,
                    email: snapshot.val().email,
                    agreed: newfriendagreed,
                    profilepicture: data
                });
            }).then(function(){
                if (newfriendsinfo.length == newfriends.length){
                    deferred.resolve(newfriendsinfo);
                }
            });
        });
    }

    return deferred.promise;
}
```